# A commutative ring whose all proper ideals are prime is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Suppose that all ideals $I \neq R$ are prime. Prove that $R$ is a field.

Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The claim is false for $R=0$.

Comment: https://yutsumura.com/if-every-proper-ideal-of-a-commutative-ring-is-a-prime-ideal-then-it-is-a-field/

Comment: **Hint** $\,(0)$ prime $\Rightarrow R$  domain.  $R$ has a nonunit $\,r\!\neq\! 0 \Rightarrow$ nonunit $r^2\!\neq 0\,$ is a [*reducible* prime $\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242)

Comment: The definition of primality comes handy. $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal immediately implies that $R$ does not have zero divisors. For any non-zero $r\in R$, by existence of $1$, we have: $r^2\in\langle r^2\rangle\implies r\in \langle r^2\rangle\tag*{}$ (by primality) which means that there exists $r'\in R$ such that $r'r^2=r$. Hence, every non-zero $r$ is a unit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First show that $R$ is a domain, by a suitable choice of ideal.

Then let $x \ne 0$, and deduce consequences from the fact that $xx \in x^2 R$.

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Comment: Did you imply we can choose a noninvertible $x \in R$, take ideal $(x^2)$?

Comment: Since $(x^2)$ is prime, we have $x \in (x^2)$

Comment: That means $x=rx^2,r \in R$

Comment: Since $(0)$ is prime, we have $1=rx$, a contradiction

Comment: How the converse?

Comment: Let $x \ne 0$. You want to prove that $x$ is invertible. The first possibility is that $(x^2)$ could be $R$, so you need to look at that case. If not, then $(x^2)$ is prime, and what you wrote also proves that $x$ is invertible. Your original question didn't ask for a converse, can you give the exact statement you're referring to?

Comment: Ehm, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Consider some $r\in R$ and examine the principal ideal generated by $r^2$.

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Comment: Well, first you'll need to verify that the cancellation law holds in this ring (how?). Assuming you've done that, suppose for the moment that the principal ideal satisfies $(r^2)=R$. In particular, this says $r$ is a multiple of $r^2$. This implies $r$ is invertible (why?). If $(r^2)\neq R$, then what may be deduced?