# Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $R$ which is maximal with respect to the property that it is proper and not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $R$ which is maximal with respect to the property that it is proper and not prime. Deduce that $I$ is contained in at most two other proper ideals of $R$.

I don't have idea. Help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hint: look at $R/I$. Ideals of $R/I$ correspond to ideals of $R$ containing $I$, so what does the condition on $I$ say about $R/I$?

Comment: $R/I$ is a field.

Comment: $I$ is not a maximal ideal; it is only maximal with respect to some funny property; $I$ is, by assumption, not even prime. Can you think of an example, actually?

Comment: All maximal ideals are prime. I don't understand the wording here. Also maximal ideals are contained in exactly 1, proper ideal of $R$ namely itself.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Can you give me more details?

Comment: $I$ is not maximal. The assumption on $I$ says that $I$ is proper and not prime; and that no proper, non-prime ideal $J$ strictly contains $I$.

Comment: @TheNumber23: Not maximal with respect to all ideals, maximal with respect to a certain class of ideals.

Comment: Can anyone think of an example? Going to the quotient ring, $R/I$ must have exactly two maximal ideals and no other proper ideals besides those two maximal ideals and $(0)$. Furthermore, $R/I$ must have zero-divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be such an ideal, and let $P$ be a minimal prime ideal over $I$.  Then in $R/P$, every proper ideal is prime.  Hence for any nonzero $a \in R/P$, $(a^2)$ is prime, so it contains $a$, so there is some $b$ such that $a^2b = a$; that is, $a(ab-1)=0$ and since $R/P$ is an integral domain, it follows that $ab=1$ and $a$ has an inverse.  So that means that $R/P$ is a field; hence $P$ is maximal.

Now consider $R/I$.  The nonzero proper ideals of $R/I$ correspond exactly to the proper ideals of $R$ strictly containing $I$, and they are all maximal.  Use the result of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626564/let-r-be-a-commutative-ring-with-1-suppose-that-every-nonzero-proper-ideal?rq=1) to deduce that there are most two maximal ideals in $R/I$, and hence at most two proper ideals of $R$ strictly containing $I$.